# Cloud Pages linked to campaign

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, campaign

I am trying to assign Cloud Pages to a Campaign in the Marketing Cloud. In the page properties I am not finding an option to link to campaign. In the campaign when I clicked landing pages the list is empty. Any tips?

Comment: What do you mean by Campaign?  An email?

Comment: I don't believe Cloud pages has been linked to SFMC Campaigns (yet?).  The landing pages option you see there is in reference to the Microsites/landing page add on (which Cloud Pages is supposed to be replacing).

Comment: @Adamspriggs  If you create a Campaign in SFMC then you can add items to the campaign: emails, subscriber list, data extension....  and Landing pages. But there are not any cloud pages listed when you click on Landing pages. It seems Cloud pages are not ready enabled to be included. Any workaround? Thanks